# Porque o script não aceita somente a letra F?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

Fiz uma expressão regular para aceitar valores de 0.0 até 10.0 e a letra F e justamente com ela estou tendo problemas, acaba negando na msg do próprio AddMethod().

```
    <html>
    <head>  
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        //Método para verificar as horas com uso de expressão regular
        $.validator.addMethod("nota", function(value, element) {  
        return this.optional(element) || /^(([F]{0-1})|((([1]{1}[0]{1})\.([0]{1}))|((([0]{1})(\d){1}))\.(\d{1})))?$/i.test(value);  
        }, "Por favor entre com uma nota válida.");

        $("#formularioContato").validate({
        // Define as regras
            rules:{
                nota:{
                    nota: "required nota",
                    required: true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                nota:{
                    required: "Digite uma nota válida ou o conceito F",
                    range: "O valor do dia deve estar entre 0.0 a 10.0 ou F"
                }
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        $("#nota").mask("*9.9");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body><form id="formularioContato" method="post">

<div align="center">
<ul>
    <li>
    <label>Nota:</label><input type="text" id="nota" name="nota"></span><br />
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A máscara mask("*9.9") não deveria ser um mask("A9.9")?    http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/

Comment: Acho que a expressão poderia ser `^(F|10\.0|\d\.\d)$`, pois "10.0" vale porém "11.0" já não vale... se o decimal for opcional, pode ser assim: `^(F|10(\.0)?|\d(\.\d)?)$`

Comment: J.Bruni essa que você me enviou funcionou porêm ele não aceita a 09.0

Answer (score 1):

O problema está nas regras (*rules*)... substitua `nota: "required nota"` por `nota: true`

```
        rules:{
            nota:{
                nota: true,
                required: true
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua expressão regular não deveria estar assim:

```
^(([F]{0,1})|((([1]{1}[0]{1})\.([0]{1}))|((([0]{1})(\d){1}))\.(\d{1})))?$
```

Acho que você cometeu um pequeno *typo*. Trocou `{0,1}` por `{0-1}`.

Comment: Não funcionou, tinha tentado uma solução semelhante também, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Aqui funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/fXac6/ A não ser que eu não tenha entendido a pergunta.

Comment: O engraçado que ele também aceita nesse site http://regex101.com/ será que é algo com os rules ?